# AWS ELB custom traffic routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, session

Is there any way to force elb to direct traffic to a particular registered instance.
if we can create a session according to maybe a meeting id or any variable and any user that wants to join this meeting gets directed to a single instance.
Or if maybe we can use any other Load balancer on aws that provides this feature.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use "application generated cookie stickiness" in ELB

Set up the ELB with application generated cookie stickiness.  Then 
set a cookie in the session with the id and it will route according to the customer application generated cookie

Further details here

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html#enable-sticky-sessions-application

Comment: hi, my dev team tried to create session cookie at application side for meetingid based routing, i gave that cookie name in the elb, but its not working, could you please maybe explain how to actually create cookie at application side. i have no idea on that

Comment: use your application framework hook for making a cookie!! all frameworks can do this.  All a cookie is is a special value in a header, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265